# withSpring doesn't work correctly when SharedValue is an object

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-reanimated-v2

I'm trying to use a SharedValue from [react-native-reanimated2](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/2.x/) to store an object (box positions). The object is of the following shape:

```js
boxPositions.value = {
  [boxId]: {x: 0, y: 0}
  ...
}
```

My goal is to update the object in the SharedValue so that it animates a specific box's position given its `id`.

To update a box's position, I'm doing the following, and applying `withSpring()` to the object's `y` property to have it animate:

```js
const moveRandomBox = () => {
  const randId = Math.floor(Math.random() * boxes.length) + 1;
  boxPositions.value = {
    ...boxPositions.value,
    [randId]: {
      x: boxPositions.value[randId].x,
      y: withSpring(boxPositions.value[randId].y - 50)
    }
  };
}
```

I'm then passing this shared value object to my box component itself, and then creating an animated style to transform the box's position:

```js
const rStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
  const boxPosition = boxPositions.value[box.id] ? ? {x: 0, y: 0};
  return {
    transform: [
      {translateX: boxPosition.x},
      {translateY: boxPosition.y} // this value should be animated
    ]
  };
}, []);
```

The problem is that this approach of applying the `withSpring()` animation causes the box to not move at all when `moveRandomBox()` is called.

However, if I change the `moveRandomBox()` function to set the `y` position to a plain value:

```js
[randId]: {
  x: boxPositions.value[randId].x,
  y: boxPositions.value[randId].y - 50 // instead of: withSpring(boxPositions.value[randId].y - 50)
}
```

and then change the `useAnimatedStyle()` hook to use the `withSpring()` animation method, it works as expected:

```js
return {
  transform: [
    {translateX: boxPosition.x},
    {translateY: withSpring(boxPosition.y)} // instead of just: boxPosition.y
  ]
};
```

In my actual code I don't want to actually do this, as I have different places where I set my box's `x` and `y` positions, and I want the animation to be different and not always the same. So I want the animation to be set when I update the box's position (like in the first appraoch), and not in the style definition (second example).

My question is: Why does the first approach of setting the animation not work, whereas the second does? What is wrong with the first approach that stops it from working? How would I go about making the first approach work? I only seem to experience this issue when the SharedValue is an object, setting a SharedValue to an individual `withSpring()` value seems to work correctly.

**[Runnable Example](https://snack.expo.dev/@clapynick/usesharedvalue-as-array-of-objects)**:
To reproduce, change the preview to iOS. Once loaded, click the button "Move random box", and you'll see none of the boxes move. If you change the code to call `withSpring()` in the `useAnimatedStyle()` hook like above and remove the `withSpring()` call from the `moveRandomBox()` method you'll see that the box does move.

Comment: It is not possible to springify (or use any other animation) on an object property. If you want to springify the y value, just define two `useSharedValues`. One for your X pos, and one for your Y pos.

Comment: This is probably because the reference to the object stays the same, so it doesn't understand the changes to a property. I'm not really into the 'references', 'copies' etc. of objects, but there are many posts online that explain this in dept.

Comment: Thanks, defining two `useSharedValues()` would work fine, but I'm trying to make this scalable, say if I had 10 boxes, or 100 boxes. I wouldn't want to create a SharedValue variable explicitly for each. I could use a loop, but as far as I'm aware that [shouldn't be done](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) unless really needed...?

Comment: In that case wouldn't it be better to create a single re-usable box component, and then loop to the amount you want?

Comment: @Kipnoedels that is actually what I am doing (you can see in the expo snack runnable example I have a Box component). I can’t put the call to useSharedValue() to create one xPos and yPos variables in there though because I need to be able to control the Box’s position outside of the Box component itself. That’s why I’ve lifted the SharedValue logic out of the box component itself and moved it into the parent (App) component. It’s also why I’ve created an object so that I can keep track of each individual Box position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, what you want is to actually two issues.

1. Springify a value inside an object.
2. Update a components 'state' rendered from a loop.

For the first issue, we've already found a solution. Instead of springifying the full object (which is not possible because of how reanimated work), you need to specify the `x` and `y` values seperatly. I'm not really into the details of how a shared value works, but it must have to be something between the two threads and having object references, where children changes are not recognized because of the way they are handled / passed along.

---

Your second issue is a totally different issue, where you want to update a single components state. In this case to move a random box. For this you need to have the box components be reusable. So their movement logic should stay inside the component itself, and not be brought up to the parent state.

For example when using a `ScrollView`, you're not lifting all their positions state up into the parent, but instead assign a `ref` which holds the functions you want to call. E.g. `scrollTo`.

This is the same for your box components. They should own their own behaviour, so that you can assign a `ref` to them and randomly get one of those refs to call the function you need. E.g. `moveBoxTo()`.

If this is not what you want, you could give each box an unique id. Something like you currently have. Since your 'random' movement seems to be static, (so always do the same). You could pass an 'id-to-move' to all the boxes and listen to that value using an `useAnimatedReaction`. In this hook you check if the id of the box matches the random id that should move, and animate its position to the expected point.

Comment: Thank you - Using a ref to expose a child method to the parent seemed to be what I was after (I'm usually used to doing it the other way around and passing a method from the parent down to the child). [This](https://snack.expo.dev/@clapynick/usesharedvalue-controlled-via-ref) is what I ended up doing, which is what I'm thinking you had in mind.

Comment: Nice work, seems good to me!